# Creating Facebook App Results in 500 Error

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to create a facebook application that i'll connect with my MVC site.  I go to developers.facebook.com, select Apps tab, and it gives me a 500 error... any idea why?  I have another account where it works fine.  What does facebook require for me to create an application?

Thanks.

Comment: File a bug report: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs - this is too localized for SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook requires an internal API to work for you to create an application; something is evidently wrong with it at the moment. What's going wrong is a mystery, hence the 500 and not a specific error. Rest assured its not just you though, I cannot register an app right now either.

Comment: I have another account which can, which is weird.  Though that account has an app already registered...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow an developers invitation link and got the same error. I also get it when browsing into the apps section generally.
Switching to a fellow developers account resulted in an instant login, so the problem is account-related.